# Calculating instantaneous and average power

Tags: power, resistors, circuit-analysis, ac

I need to calculate the average and instantaneous power for the following circuit:

A voltage supply in series with a resistor: V1 = 150sin(wt)V and R1 = 25ohms

[image]

I understand that t = time, w = 2*pi*f but what is confusing is that I am not given either time or frequency.  Do I just assume that sin(wt) = 0 and V = 150V?

If this is the case then is the instantaneous power just P = VI (or (V^2)/R)?

How do I calculate average power if Pavg = VIcos(phi)?

This is a practice paper for an exam, not homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instantaneous power is, as you surmised, \$ P= V^2/R=900 \sin^2(\omega t)\,\rm W \$.

The average value of \$ \sin^2(\omega t) \$ over any whole number of cycles is \$ 1/2 \$, so the average power is \$ 450\,\rm W \$.

To address your other formula, \$P=VI\cos\phi\$, observe that the peak voltage is \$150\,\rm V\$, so the RMS voltage is \$150/\sqrt2\,\rm V\$, and the RMS current is \$6/\sqrt 2\,\rm A\$.  Since the load is resistive, the phase angle \$\phi\$ is zero, and the (average) power is \$900/2 = 450\,\rm W\$ as before.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, P(instantaneous) = V^2/R so you can use that here.
Average Power Absorbed by element is given by R(I^2)/2 so here I = 150/25 Amps. So Avg Power absorbed by Resistor = 450 Watts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, notice that when the following voltage \$\displaystyle\text{V}\left(t\right)\$ is applied across a resitor:

$$\text{V}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\tag1$$

We know that the current through the resistor \$\displaystyle\text{R}\$ is given by:

$$\text{I}\left(t\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}\left(t\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}}=\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\tag2$$

So, the instantaneous power \$\displaystyle\text{P}\left(t\right)\$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{P}\left(t\right)&=\text{V}\left(t\right)\text{I}\left(t\right)\\
\\
&=\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\sin^2\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)
\end{split}\tag3
\end{equation}

So, the average power \$\displaystyle\overline{\text{P}}\$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\overline{\text{P}}&=\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{n}}\int\limits_0^\text{n}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{n}}\int\limits_0^\text{n}\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\sin^2\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{n}}\int\limits_0^\text{n}\sin^2\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{n}}\int\limits_\varphi^{\omega\text{n}+\varphi}\sin^2\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{du}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{n}}\int\limits_\varphi^{\omega\text{n}+\varphi}\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle2}-\frac{\displaystyle\cos\left(2\text{u}\right)}{\displaystyle2}\right)\space\text{du}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{n}}\cdot\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle2}\int\limits_\varphi^{\omega\text{n}+\varphi}1\space\text{du}-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle2}\int\limits_\varphi^{\omega\text{n}+\varphi}\cos\left(2\text{u}\right)\space\text{du}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{n}}\cdot\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{n}}{\displaystyle2}-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle2}\int\limits_\varphi^{\omega\text{n}+\varphi}\cos\left(2\text{u}\right)\space\text{du}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{n}}\cdot\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{n}}{\displaystyle2}-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle2}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle2}\int\limits_{2\varphi}^{2\left(\omega\text{n}+\varphi\right)}\cos\left(\text{s}\right)\space\text{ds}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{n}}\cdot\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{n}}{\displaystyle2}-\frac{\displaystyle-\sin\left(2\left(\omega\text{n}+\varphi\right)\right)-\left(-\sin\left(2\varphi\right)\right)}{\displaystyle4}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{n}}\cdot\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{n}}{\displaystyle2}-\frac{\displaystyle\sin\left(2\varphi\right)-\sin\left(2\left(\omega\text{n}+\varphi\right)\right)}{\displaystyle4}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega}{\displaystyle2}-\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\sin\left(2\varphi\right)-\sin\left(2\left(\omega\text{n}+\varphi\right)\right)}{\displaystyle4\text{n}}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega}{\displaystyle2}-\underbrace{\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\sin\left(2\varphi\right)-\sin\left(2\left(\omega\text{n}+\varphi\right)\right)}{\displaystyle4\text{n}}}_{=\space0}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega}{\displaystyle2}-0\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\omega}{\displaystyle2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle2\text{R}}
\end{split}\tag4
\end{equation}